# autoNumeric won't allow decimal input from numeric keyboard / Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have [autoNumeric](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric) set up on an input field with these settings

```
[
    {"digitGroupSeparator" : ""},
    {"decimalCharacter" : ","},
    {"modifyValueOnWheel" : false},
    {"minimumValue" : "0"}
]
```

The decimal separator is a comma. When comma is pressed on the regular keyboard, it appears on the input field as it should. However, when pressed on the numeric keyboard, nothing appears. This happends only on IE, on Chrome/FF it works as it should, a comma appears.

I tested the JavaScript codes of both IE and Chrome on this service: http://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html

They are identical. Normal keyboard comma press:

```
keydown  keyCode=188       which=188       charCode=0        
keypress keyCode=44  (,)   which=44  (,)   charCode=44  (,)  
keyup    keyCode=188       which=188       charCode=0
```

Numeric keyboard comma press:

```
keydown  keyCode=110 (n)   which=110 (n)   charCode=0        
keypress keyCode=44  (,)   which=44  (,)   charCode=44  (,)  
keyup    keyCode=110 (n)   which=110 (n)   charCode=0
```

Should this be filed as a bug to autoNumeric? It should accept the separator also from the numeric keyboard. Any workaround possible?

**EDIT**: Here's a JSFiddle to test: https://jsfiddle.net/g1wumdt7/3/

Comment: Providing a snippet or fiddle is always helpful to inspect any issue associated with the question.

Comment: JSFiddle added.

Comment: Your numeric keyboard has a comma separator? The fiddle seems to be working fine on chrome. You didn't mistakenly swap the digitGroupSeparator with the decimalCharacter did you?

If the script has a bug for IE probably you can use the default dot separator as the decimalCharacter and later replace it with a comma when you want to use it

Comment: Yes, the numeric keyboard has a comma next to zero on the bottom row. Pressing that on a normal text input outputs `,` also on IE. Still it outputs nothing on an autoNumeric input that should allow `,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"decimalCharacterAlternative": "."` which will work as alternative for your main decimal character when pressed.

Here is more [options](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric#options)

```js
var anSettings = {
  "digitGroupSeparator" : "",
  "decimalCharacter" : ",",
  "modifyValueOnWheel" : false,
  "minimumValue" : "0",
  "decimalCharacterAlternative": "."
};
AutoNumeric.multiple('.an', anSettings);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/autonumeric/4.1.0/autoNumeric.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" class="an">
```

Update: Thanks to @Alex, to add AutoNumeric to multiple field use [AutoNumeric.mulitple](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric#initialize-multiple-autonumeric-objects-at-once)

Comment: This works, but i don't really understand why. The key on the numeric keyboard outputs a comma "," also on IE, not a dot "." so adding a dot as `decimalCharacterAlternative` shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @lofihelsinki that is the functionality of AutoNumeric right, you specified decimalCharacter as `,` and there is no groupseparator. so it will work like that. Can you show some example, what output you want to get?

Comment: Sure, but i don't understand why IE doesn't output `,` from the numeric keyboard where the other browsers did. On our kb layout, there is `,` in the numeric keyboard. So typing `1234,56` outputs `123456` in IE, `1234,56` on Chrome & FF. Still seems like a bug in autoNumeric to me. `.` should not have anything to do with it. Not pressing any `.` key at all.

Comment: @lofihelsinki I am not able to check your case, its a `period (.)` on my numpad.

Comment: I guess it's a comma in countries where the decimal delimiter in a comma, i.e. finnish keyboard: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-6642/images/BR.finnish.tif.gif
It's possible to test it by changing your kb layout in the localization settings :)

Comment: @lofihelsinki tried with finnish layout, working for me, IE V-11.0.96

Comment: You mean working without the `decimalCharacterAlternative` fix? Not here, tested with 3 different machines/keyboards. Same IE version.

Comment: @lofihelsinki my answer snippet, changed the keyboard layout to finnish which gives `,` (replace numpad `.`), it works and prints `,` in IE V11.0.96

Comment: Ok, you didn't really get the point about the different kb layouts, but anyway your answer & snippet works for me too. That's the main thing.

Comment: @lofihelsinki ok finally got your problem;) will check about that, if you don't have any problem with `decimalCharacterAlternative` you use it. I will check that issue. :p Check this fiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/g1wumdt7/11/) in IE it gives key as`'decimal'` while others gives `','`

Comment: Quick note: instead of calling `$(".an").each(...`, you can just write `AutoNumeric.multiple('.an', anSettings)`; much simpler!